# Maximum number of connections using websocket

Tags: java, javascript, html

As all of us might know, websocket maintains opened connection between server and client to achieve server push not like server pull where the connection wouldn't remains open. My question is how many number of TCP connections can be open at one time? What is the limitation of server push compared to server pull in this regard?

Comment: Think this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16426868/3112803

Answer (score 0):

Default maximum number of websocket connections allowed in FireFox is 200.
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets#Gecko_7.0

From the comment given in line #48 of http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/socket/client_socket_pool_manager.cc?r1=128044&r2=128043&pathrev=128044 seems to talk of dynamic numbers with minimum of 6 for normal socket pool and 30 for websocket pool.
More Info: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-reviews/4sHNK-Eotn0

Comment: I think the question is asking about server side instead of the client side.