# Using Nodejs and Socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, livechat

I want to make an 'online chat module' for a supporting website. the project must be done by nodejs. so I want to use socket io library for this purpose.
how many current users could the socket.io support?
what type of os and hardware do you recommend?
thank you.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, how many current users could the socket.io support?

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly ask exactly that.  It depends upon your server OS, configuration, hardware, network and traffic profile, but there are socket.io configurations that support tens of thousands of connections so 100 should be easy.

Comment: the question was edited. what type of os and hardware do you recommend?

Comment: OS and hardware recommendations are off-topic for stack overflow.  There are probably other hardware-focused stacks in the stackexchange family where that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your server OS, configuration, hardware, network and traffic profile, but there are socket.io configurations that support tens of thousands of connections so 100 should be easy.

See these for more info:

[Maximum concurrent Socket.IO connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872788/maximum-concurrent-socket-io-connections)

[Realtime node.js stress test with socket.io](https://bocoup.com/blog/node-stress-test-analysis)

[Node.js with 1M concurrent connections](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/08/19/node-js-w1m-concurrent-connections/)