# Don't receive updates when subscribed to 9 Websocket channels

Tags: python, api, websocket

I am using Bitfinex WebSockets V2 with Python library https://github.com/Crypto-toolbox/btfxwss. I have a problem with receiving updates when subscribed to many websocket channels. The issue is that I need to subscribe to 3 order book updates, 3 ticker updates, and 3 trades updates (total - 9 channels) at Bitfinex Websocket API. And I just stop receiving updates after like several minutes of normal work with no errors (or keep receiving them, but with huge delay). So can you help me to find out what's wrong ? Are there any limitations for Websocket connections? Because when I subscribe to 1 order book updates using the same code, everything is OK.

Comment: Can you help us with some more info?

Comment: No websockets in general shouldn't be affected by that little a number of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872788/maximum-concurrent-socket-io-connections

Comment: @DaveIdito i'm connecting like in btfxwss docs: `# order books
        self.wss.subscribe_to_order_book('SANETH')
        self.wss.subscribe_to_order_book('SANBTC')
        self.wss.subscribe_to_order_book('SANUSD')
        # tickers
        self.wss.subscribe_to_ticker('ETHUSD')
        self.wss.subscribe_to_ticker('ETHBTC')
        self.wss.subscribe_to_ticker('BTCUSD')
        # trades
        self.wss.subscribe_to_trades('SANETH')
        self.wss.subscribe_to_trades('SANBTC')
        self.wss.subscribe_to_trades('SANUSD')`. where self.wss = BtfxWss()

Comment: Then I process updates in separate Threads like this:         `while True:
            if not wss_q.empty():`

Comment: And everything works fine when I'm subscribed to 1 order book + 2 tickers for example. But when I subscribe to more channels, I receive updates with huge delays(I know that by checking order books on website and comparing them to my order books). And my in-memory data is outdated

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of threading?

Comment: Well, all threads modify their own variables. So yes, I'm sure. And when I'm running for example 3 threads, there are no issues.