# How to add Real time functionality to MERN stack project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, webrtc

I am trying to create an e-learning system that supports virtual learning.  My current task is to implement real-time conferencing to support virtual lesson conducting.

I have read and seen numerous videos of how to implement this.  I found out that i could use webRTC and socket.io to implement this functionality.  I have two questions about this.

1. Will implementing webRTC allow 50 people or more to interact virtually without difficulty in video or audio connection(i am thinkiung of a lecturer conducting a class of 150 students).

Answer (score 0):

This may help you [Maximum concurrent Socket.IO connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872788/maximum-concurrent-socket-io-connections). The maximum number of simultaneous connections is normally greater than 50. Keep in mind that your host server and network bandwidth should be able to handle your application's load.